# No me guarda datos en mi Base de Datos por PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Ando iniciando el mundo de la programación con un ejercicio en PHP con una conexión a base de datos; el problema viene aquí.

No me guarda registro alguno, el error me muestra al parecer en el query porque me muestra "F!" ni bien ejecuto el botón.

Sé lo básico que es, pero solo estoy practicando, disculpen la simpleza.

Este es mi Base de Datos:

```
-- Base de datos: `inscripcion`
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `alumno`
--

CREATE TABLE `alumno` (
  `codMatri_alumno` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `dni_alumno` char(8) NOT NULL,
  `contrasenia_alumno` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `nombres_alumno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos_alumno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `fechNac_alumno` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `direccion_alumno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `telefPer_alumno` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefCasa_alumno` char(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_alumno` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `especialidad_alumno` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ciclo_alumno` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_alumno` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `codOperBan_alumno` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

ALTER TABLE `alumno`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`codMatri_alumno`);
COMMIT;
```

Este es mi conexión a mi DB

```
<?php  
$servidor="localhost";
$usuario="root";
$clave="";
$baseDeDatos="inscripcion";
$enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
?>
```

Y todo esto es mi igualación de los input text con variables además de la consulta SQL.

```
 <input type="submit" name="btnGuardar"value="Guardar">
      <?php
      if(isset($_POST['btnGuardar'])){
        $enlace = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $baseDeDatos);
        $fechaNac = $_POST['txtFecha']; 
        $codMatri = $_POST['txtDNI'];
        $nombreAlu = $_POST['txtNombre'];
        $apellidoAlu = $_POST['txtApellidos'];
        $contraAlu = $_POST['txtDNI'];
        $sexoAlu = $_POST['selSexo'];
        $dniAlu = $_POST['txtDNI'];
        $dirAlu = $_POST['txtDireccion'];
        $telefPer = $_POST['txtTelefonoP'];
        $telefCasa = $_POST['txtTelefonoC'];
        $emailAlu = $_POST['txtEmail'];
        $especialidad = $_POST['cbEspecialidad'];
        $ciclo = $_POST['cbCiclo'];
        $tipo = "NV";
        $codigoOpBan = $_POST['txtCOB'];
        mysqli_query($enlace,"INSERT INTO alumno(codMatri_alumno,
                                        dni_alumno,
                                        contrasenia_alumno,
                                        nombres_alumno,
                                        apellidos_alumno,
                                        sexo,
                                        fechNac_alumno,
                                        direccion_alumno,
                                        telefPer_alumno,
                                        telefCasa_alumno,
                                        email_alumno,
                                        especialidad_alumno,
                                        ciclo_alumno,
                                        tipo_alumno,
                                        codOperBan_alumno)
                                VALUES($codMatri,
                                        $dniAlu,
                                        $contraAlu,
                                        $nombreAlu,
                                        $apellidoAlu,
                                        $sexoAlu,
                                        $fechaNac,
                                        $dirAlu,
                                        $telefPer,
                                        $telefCasa,
                                        $emailAlu,
                                        $especialidad,
                                        $ciclo,
                                        $tipo,
                                        $codigoOpBan)") or die ("F!");
    }
```

Además, tiene que ver lo que le coloque al form action ya que lo tengo con este valor "#"?

Comment: Bueno para empezar ese insert esta mal, vos estas mandando todos los campos iguales.. y no van todos iguales.. las cadenas van entre comillas simples, los numeros si estan bien, la fecha depende la base va tambien con comillas simples.. y para cuando estas aprendiendo, no tires ningun error. Mejor que te muestre el error real que esta ocurriendo....

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Como dijeron, ese los valores cadenas y fechas van obligatorios en comillas simples, los numéricos es opcional. Te puede ayudar asignar la consulta a una variable, por ejemplo `$query = "INSERT INTO alumno..."`. Luego haces un `echo $query;`. Y lo que se imprima lo pegas directo en tu interfaz de base de datos (PHPMyAdmin, Workbench, etc) y allá tendrás más información para corregir los errores de SQL